# Is ANOVA the same as running 3 t-tests?

Tags: anova, t-test

I have a group of subjects which did tests under 3 different conditions.

If I now want to compare variables with a ANOVA, is it right that I get the same p-values as if I would run 3 t-tests comparing each of the conditions with each other?

Comment: The basic problem with the three t-tests is that their results are not independent: each compares a group to the *same* reference group.  If you instead had three independent sets of reference data (six groups in all), then three t-tests would work. But even then it would be an inferior procedure, because you could do better by combining the three reference groups and running an ANOVA.

Answer (score 2):

Well, think about it. You get one p value from anova, three p values from the t tests. How are you going to compare one apple with three oranges? So the answer is NO.

Comment: I believe the OP may be asking about the difference between performing three *post hoc* ANOVA comparisons and three separate t-tests.

Comment: Partly in response to @whuber. The ANOVA tells you *whether* the means differ, the t tests have hope of showing you *how* they differ. The latter is more informative, but you should correct the p values for multiplicity, e.g. via the Tukey procedure. The ANOVA is completely optional, in my opinion. You can do the comparisons pre-hoc if you like.

Answer (score 1):

No. Running three t-tests is not the same as running a single ANOVA. The critical difference is that each time you run a t-test, you'll inherit a Type-I error. Your overall error rate is proportional to the number of individual t-test that you run. The more you do, the more likely you will get a false positive.

We don't want to do this. Instead, we partition the variance in ANOVA. The single F-value will tell us whether any group is differ. We will have only a single p-value instead of three p-values.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, they are nothing alike.

We use an ANOVA to tell if one or more of the 3+ groups is different from the others. If that p value is significant, we then use a Tukey post-hoc test to determine the differences between groups. A Student T-test is not appropriate for comparing more than two groups.

The ANOVA, like other statistic tests, attempts to separate signal from noise -- it tests if there is any [variation between groups that is not likely to be caused by variation within each group.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance#Logic_of_ANOVA) By partitioning the sources of variation and comparing them, we can approximate a signal to noise ratio. High F-values are more likely with small sample sizes; the computer will spit out a useful p-value based on the F value and the degrees of freedom.

Comparing three T-tests just does not work very well. The T-test is a basic (though generally robust) tool for comparing two sample groups, but that is the extent of its purpose. The ANOVA was designed to better assess datasets of 3+ sample groups.

Comment: Welcome to our site! Although all this is correct, it doesn't really explain *why* ANOVA is better than three t-tests. Would you be able to share your insight about that?

Comment: The OP didn't ask if/why one was better than the other. I can write an explanation of why ANOVA is more appropriate than T-tests, but I do not think it fits in the scope of this question.

Comment: Although they did not ask explicitly why, this site favors explanations that go beyond the mere "what" of a situation.  When only the "what" is appropriate, without further explanation, then we seek references to authoritative sources to back up an answer.